# How to allow specific users/groups to read but not edit draft files?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, custom-permission-level

Here's the issue: I have a library, configured to have minor and major versions and to require content approval. There are 3 broad audiences for the library's content: lets call them External, Internal and Authors. External gets 'Read' permission so that they only see published major version material; Authors get 'Contribute' so that they can work on drafts. The issue is with Internal, who I want to be able to see and open the draft material, but not edit it. I have explored the forums, SharePoint library settings and custom permission levels (specifically one that equates to 'Contribute level less Edit') but it seems that the Edit check mark in the custom permission specifics is what prevents the user from seeing the draft material and I am coming up blank. Any pointers out there, or am I asking for the impossible? Could any use be made of the Pending file state?

Answer (score 0):

If you have specified the users who can see the draft items in the draft item security section in versioning settings in the document library, it is difficult to be achieved in a document library.

You could store published items and draft items separately in two document libraries, then set different permissions for separate groups in the document libraries.

The External group only has read permission on document library which stores publish items.

The Contribute group have edit permission on two document libraries.

The Internal group have read permission on two document libraries.

Comment: Thanks Amy, but that’s the situation I’m trying to avoid. In fact, it’s what we do now and it leads to configuration control and version history problems.